# Passing context to airflow task with PythonVirtualOperator

Tags: python, airflow

I have the following setup for a DAG:

```
def func(**context):
      metric_name = f'dag.{context["dag"].dag_id}.{context["task"].task_id}.dag_runs'

task = PythonVirtualenvOperator(
            task_id='task-id',
            python_callable=func,
            system_site_packages=False,
            use_dill=True,
            pip_install_options=pip_install_options,
            op_kwargs={},
            dag=dag,
        provide_context=True
        )
```

My issue is that the `dag` and `task` parameters don't exist in the context passed

After some browsing, it seems like dill and pickle can't serialize the context variables when using `PythonVirtualenvOperator` therefore i'm not seeing the context variables I need when the `func` function is called.

Is there any way I can access the `dag_id` and `task_id` context variables when using the `PythonVirtualenvOperator`?